# preg_replace on HTML page gives net ::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: php, html, curl, transfer-encoding

I have a simple curl call that retrieves HTML page from the server, then `preg_replace()` that inserts something in the page and then the result of that is echoed back to the browser.

What I noticed is that if HTTP server that curl is trying to get HTML page from, uses header `'Transfer-Enoding: chunked`', html output will be somehow encoded(I noticed a few strange signs) and `preg_replace()` call will do the job but the browser will just get `ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING` and won't load the page. There must be a way to replace part of the page without messing up chunked encoding  ?

Answer (score 1):

Chunked transfer-encoding is a HTTP 1.1 feature where the server doesn't know the size of the resource when it starts to send the data so it sends a series "chunks" to the client, each chunk preceded with the size (in number of bytes in hexadecimal) of the chunk.

Alas, if you *insert* data into a chunk, you must change the size of the chunk too when you send it to the browser. Alternatively of course, you get the full thing, do your replacement and send out the entire response in one single chunk (or even without chunks).

A proper HTTP 1.1 client should be able to decode the chunks and a proper HTTP 1.1 server should send a legitimate series of chunks (a somewhat common server-side error is to leave out the final zero-sized chunk).

See here for the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1